# Cannot find Module 'date-fns' After npm audit fix

Tags: node.js, date-fns

My react app was working fine until I ran `npm audit fix`. I am now getting an error:

```
Test suite failed to run

Cannot find module 'date-fns/addDays' from 'date-fns-utils.js'

However, Jest was able to find:
        './index.css'
        './index.js'
        './index.test.js'

You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently 
['web.js', 'js', 'web.ts', 'ts', 'web.tsx', 'tsx', 'json', 'web.jsx', 'jsx', 'node'].
```

On one of the tests during `npm test`

What could this be? Let me know what details I need to add. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you delete: node_modules and package-lock.json and run npm install.

Comment: check if you need to update npm and nodejs for new version

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try explicitly downloading the `date-fns` library and seeing if this gets rid of your current error message of:

> Cannot find module 'date-fns/addDays' from 'date-fns-utils.js'

which indicates that the issue is due to being unable to locate the `addDays` module within the `date-fns` package. I suspect `npm audit fix` may have had an issue installing the more up-to-date version of the `date-fns` library.

Perhaps you could try the following and seeing if this resolves your issue:

```
rm package-lock.json
npm i -S date-fns 

# or with yarn
yarn add date-fns
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately, I'm getting the same error still. I added a little more of the error message -- maybe that helps? Thanks!